# How do I know the cause of error in my Facebook app dashboard

Tags: facebook

I see some errors in my App dashboard(section 'API Stats', tab 'errors'), but it doesn't show the error code or a readable message error, only a graph showing the number of errors in each day. Is there any way to know the cause of the error for each call my app did?

[image]

Comment: Long ago - did you find an answer? I'm getting errors in the dashboard too, and can't find the complete log or error code or anything.